# Datetime picker how to show all year

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, datetimepicker

I am using jquery datetime picker. But it shows year from 2003 to 2023. I want it should show from before some 19 type of years. How will change this?

I put screenshot,

[image: Datetime picker showing]

Please any suggestions?

Comment: do you mean 19 years from now?

Comment: @Mahan I assume he means 199X (1998, 1997 ...) years

Comment: No.Year is showing from 2000. i want 1990 like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the range of years using `yearRange` in datepicker.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ yearRange: "1990:2013" });
```

Check this [jQuery documentation link](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-yearRange) for further reference.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following `yearRange` argument to the datepicker options and tweak the values to get the ranges you want

```
    yearRange: "-18:-0"
```